# Dbeaver Datasource 'mariaDB-xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' not found

Tags: connection, datasource, dbeaver

I had just started using Dbeaver 22.1.5 on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. I create connection (that showed in the General section), then I created a ER diagram (file extension erd).
Then I created multiple connections to different databases on localhost. Deleted some previous connection. I didn't think must about deleting connection, thinking I could always create new connections.
But now I am unable to use any connection in any Diagram.
I tried purge the dbeaver-ce using apt and all the configuration folder that I could found.

```
sudo apt purge dbeaver-ce
rm -rf /home/adeel/.eclipse/
rm -rf /home/adeel/.local/share/DBeaverData/
rm -rf /var/www/html/hrdc/model/.dbeaver
```

But to no avail.

I searched and came to know that dbeaver saved it configuration in folder file

```
/home/adeel/.local/share/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/.dbeaver/data-sources.json
```

There in the connection array datasource subarray. I even created a new connection and copied the newly created connection id into the diagram erd datasource id but it didn't worked.

I guess password etc is saved in file

```
/home/adeel/.local/share/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/.dbeaver/credentials-config.json
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After countless hours of trying to edit the erd (diagram file using text editor) or fiddling the configuration files and folder but still just could make it to open.

I even purging the dbeaver app and reinstalling does not solved the problem. But finally today I finally corrected it.

dbeaver creates datasource with some random id number; Problem is dbeaver saves that datasource id in the diagram file. So if you deleted that connection this file would also not open. Totally stupid idea. I guess they might had this screwed idea that datasource would make this diagram some how secure.

---

### Solution

1. Get the new datasource id that is working

Right click the new connection > Select edit connection > click the test connection > Click details > copy the id

2. Open the diagram in any text editor and replace the previous id with the new id.

And that it. (close the diagram if it is already opened and) reopen it.